# Android PhoneStateListener wrong state

Tags: android, phone-state-listener

I have the following code to receive phone state in my application:

```
private PhoneStateListener phoneListener = new PhoneStateListener(){
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String incomingNumber){
        switch(state){
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.i(TAG, "IDLE");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Log.i(TAG, "OFFHOOK");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                Log.i(TAG, "RINGING");
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

All works fine on two emulators (Android 6.0 and Android 4.4). But on my real device (android 4.4, Oukitel Original One) I've got the following output while ringing:

```
RINGING
IDLE //in real I'm still ringing here.
IDLE //real stop ringing
```

Are there any cunning features or it's just a bug in the firmware? Unfortunately, my search didn't lead to anything.

UPD
It works fine for some devices, for other devices, it works as described above.

Some more details. I set this listener in onStartCommand of my service. Service started from a broadcast receiver if it got TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING stare.

UPD2
Well, I found a solution. Broadcast receiver is working properly, so I've just switched to Receiver notifications. But it really interesting, what's wrong with PhoneStateListener. If someone has any ideas, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this on 4.4 by having the service make a startForeground notification while calling to keep the service alive.  Your issue might be somewhere else but it might be worth giving this a try.

In my service onCreate:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon1)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("description")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

    startForeground(1337, notification);
```